# My mongodb doc will not save and I can't figure it out?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Scenario: I have an endpoint on my nodejs server to edit a return address on order docs. The client and endpoint communicate just fine and when I console log the updated order doc the address is even changed, but it never actually saves in the DB. here is the endpoint:

```
const editShipsFromAddress = async (req, res) => {
  const { orderId, address, country, city, state, zipcode } = req.body;

  try {
    const order = await Order.findById(orderId);

    order.item.shipsFrom.address = address;
    order.item.shipsFrom.country = country;
    order.item.shipsFrom.state = state;
    order.item.shipsFrom.city = city;
    order.item.shipsFrom.zipcode = zipcode;

    const savedOrder = await order.save();

    console.log(savedOrder);

    return res.json('Address updated');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json('Server error');
  }
};
```

all orders start with order.item as an empty obj.

Comment: I just had a similar issue with a post call where I got no errors, the server returning the correct new document, but mongo not saving it. Turned out the controller had a prop that wasn't added to the model, so the doc didn't save. It hadn't crossed my mind to check before posting it here, and someone pointing it out. Be sure to check all your files (index, routes, controller, model)

Answer (score 0):

*Mongoose .findById() returns a query. Mongoose queries are not promises. Instead you can execute the query using .exec() which in turn returns a promise.* 
 For example:

```
Order.findById(orderId,(err,data) => {
 if (!err) {
    data.save(function (err) {
      // do something
    });
  }
});
```