# MongoDB not saving value, call responds fine on postman, no errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJS backend call with MongoDB. This particular api call was working fine for a long time, and when testing out something on the frontend, I realized the call was not going through. I've checked the routes, controller, index files, and tested the call through Postman which works fine, no errors, and even returns an ObjectId (which means it must be interacting with the database, right?). However, when I search the mongo shell nothing comes back, which tells me it is not saving. I cannot find anything wrong and get no errors anywhere along the way. I checked on MongoDB Atlas, the collection only has 4kb of data so it is not that it is 'too full' and have tested all the other api calls (get, patch, delete) which work fine and have no issues like this in my other collections.

Even weirder, during the save call I push the ID to 2 other collection's documents as a ref. The Mongo shell does show that the new Id is populating to the other documents, but yet it is not saving the actual document... which should be happening prior to the push and needs to happen in order to get the ObjectId

Below is the controller for adding a new Visit document, the route for it, and the response from postman. I really have no idea of how else to determine what is taking place.

Controller

```
exports.addVisit = async (req, res) => {
    const hoursValue = getTotalHours(req.body.visitStart, req.body.visitEnd)
    
    try {
    const visit = new Visit({
        totalHours: hoursValue,
        user: req.body.user,
        client: req.body.client,
        visitStart: req.body.visitStart,
        visitEnd: req.body.visitEnd,
        location: req.body.location
    });
    const user = await User.findById(req.body.user);
    const client = await Client.findById(req.body.client);
    visit.user = user._id
    visit.client = client._id
    visit.save();
    user.visits.push(visit._id);
    user.save();
    client.visits.push(visit._id);
    client.save();


    console.log(visit)
    console.log(user)
    console.log(client)
    res.status(201).send(visit);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400)
        res.send({ error: "Error adding visit", error})
    }

}
```

Route

```
router.route("/visits").post(addVisit)
```

Postman call to: http://localhost:5000/visitapi/visits

```
{
  "client": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
  "location": "Home",
  "user": "62410a1dcaac9a3d0528de7a",
  "visitStart": "2022-10-12T17:00:00.000Z",
  "visitEnd": "2022-10-12T19:00:11.000Z"
}
```

Postman response

```
{
    "client": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
    "user": "62410a1dcaac9a3d0528de7a",
    "location": "Home",
    "visitStart": "2022-10-12T17:00:00.000Z",
    "visitEnd": "2022-10-12T19:00:11.000Z",
    "totalHours": 2,
    "goals": [],
    "id": "635302bb48e85ff6ad17ee59"
}
```

NodeJs console logging the same new document with no errors:

```
{
  client: new ObjectId("6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4"),
  user: new ObjectId("62410a1dcaac9a3d0528de7a"),
  location: 'Home',
  visitStart: 2022-10-12T17:00:00.000Z,
  visitEnd: 2022-10-12T19:00:11.000Z,
  totalHours: 2,
  _id: new ObjectId("635302bb48e85ff6ad17ee59"),
  goals: []
}
```

MongoShell showing the Client collection document stored the new Visit document Id:

```
visits: [
      ObjectId("6257158d157e807e51c7e009"),
      ObjectId("62fd852a252b83f4bc8f9782"),
      ObjectId("63056cee252b83f4bc8f97e9"),
      ObjectId("634ee01ec582da494032c73e"),
      ObjectId("634ee09cc582da494032c7aa"),
      ObjectId("634ee3d6ddbe3f7e6641d69e"),
      ObjectId("634efcf1ddbe3f7e6641d6f9"),
      ObjectId("634efdd3ddbe3f7e6641d71b"),
      ObjectId("635029937da8972360d907c1"),
      ObjectId("6350a0e37da8972360d9084f"),
      ObjectId("635302bb48e85ff6ad17ee59") //_id matches the same returned by Postman/ NodeJS
    ],
```

Again, everything goes through with no errors on postman or the front or back end, and the backend even logs the returns the new document but no new document is being saved to the DB unless I manually pass it in the Mongosh shell, and only for this one collection. Totally lost, I'd appreciate any guidance on how to explore/ resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Seems pretty similar to this question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145377/my-mongodb-doc-will-not-save-and-i-cant-figure-it-out

Comment: It certainly is similar behavior, however, in that post they're updating a doc using findById(), in my case, the findById() only is used to find the ref's to push the new Id to, and that aspect is working fine even though the newly added Visit doc is not being stored in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited to include the solution based on the discussion in comment

The problem could be in the mongoose schema. If the property names do not match, mongoose will simply ignore the mismatched properties.

---

#### Previous answer

Those mongodb calls are expected to be async. You might want to add `await` to all those.

```js
    visit.user = user._id
    visit.client = client._id
    await visit.save(); // <- this
    user.visits.push(visit._id);
    await user.save(); // <- this
    client.visits.push(visit._id);
    await client.save(); // <- and this
```

Comment: I tried that out and ran the call on postman, but it gets stuck in 'sending request' with no response. Even if that was the only issue, it wouldn't explain why the calls were going through without issue for a couple months before this issue started.

Comment: May be you should check if the db connection was established correctly. May be someone changed the password, or the IP address got changed. Or better still, check the Mongoose schema. May be someone changed the property name. Usually the document does not get saved correctly because mongoose will reject any unrecognized property.

Comment: Dude that was it. I didn't even think to check the model and was running in circles looking at the controller/ routes/ db connection. Thank you so much

Comment: Great to know. I always wished that mongoose threw some kind of error for such cases. I have been in that scenario way many times that I would like to admit. I have updated my answer. Please mark it as the accepted solution.